# Missing pound signs in Franchise font causing it to break

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, webfonts

I've got a Wordpress built blog and I'm using the font Franchise (http://www.dafont.com/franchise.font) for the .entry-title H1s.

Franchise doesn't have pound signs so whenever the user puts one in the title it breaks. It shows Franchise up until the pound sign, then the remaining characters afterwards come out in Arial. Anyone got any idea what I can do to fix this? I don't mind just the pound sign being in a different font but I'm not sure how to get it to just ignore it & make the remaining characters still be in Franchise following the pound sign?

An example of the issue can be found here - http://www.legalcheek.com/page/2/?s=%C2%A3

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include all relevant (PHP) code.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS Problem. So a visible example would be nice too

Comment: Sorry I've posted this in the wrong account! I'll just do it again in the right one :) ... ok it won't let me, I'll add an example!

Comment: If you know that the pound sign is always unavailable for this font, could you just ensure that this glyph is rendered in a different font? A span tag with a special class will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the font

> The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not simply stop at the first font named in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an available font does not have a glyph that can display a character needed, the later available fonts are tried. However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-family

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I've fixed it by wrapping a span around pound signs.